# Cannot apt-get update from inside my docker container if connected to bridge network

Tags: ubuntu, networking, debian, docker, apt

I am trying to understand, why I am unable to run `apt-get update` from within my docker containers, either `debian:latest` or `ubuntu:latest`.

- I am able to `ping 8.8.8.8` or other address from within the container
- I am able to `ping google.com` or other domains from within the container
- `apt-get update` works if I start the container with `--network host`
- `apt-get update` does not work if the container is connected to the default `bridge` network or any other user defined network with adapter set to bridge
- The host is a virtual machine managed by openstack
- Everything works as expected on my computer (not openstack, not virtual)

`apt-get update` will time out with:

```
root@66230c3e7572:/# apt update
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease                           
  Connection failed [IP: 199.232.138.132 80]
Err:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 151.101.194.132 80]
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease              
  Connection failed [IP: 199.232.138.132 80]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 199.232.138.132 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 151.101.194.132 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 199.232.138.132 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I would like to find out why `apt-get udpate` is not working while I'm connected to any `bridge` network on the virtual machine. So any hints on how to debug this problem are very appreciated.

Comment: Did you do this yesterday morning? Try again today. This looks related to the Fastly outage.

Comment: Fastly was not the problem, the same behavior still persists.

I noticed something else:
While I can run `wget google.com` and get the `index.html` I am unable to `wget https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2018/04/file_example_AVI_1920_2_3MG.avi` for example.

Answer (score 6):

After hours and hours I was able to solve the problem

**The MTU of the docker's bridge network has to match to the MTU of host's the network adapter**

In my case the MTU of eth0 (host) was set to 1450 while MTU of docker0 was set to 1500

You can change the MTU by either

- editing your docker.service as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300497/docker-container-not-connecting-to-https-endpoints
- add "mtu": to `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and `systemctl restart docker`

In case you don't have a `/etc/docker/daemon.json` just create one:

```
# /etc/docker/daemon.json
# adjust the MTU accordingly to the hosts network adapter

{
    "mtu":1450
}
```

Don't forget to restart docker.service: `systemctl restart docker.service`

### Further details:

If you wan't to check the settings use `ip` and compare the mtu value

```
$ ip a

2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> **mtu 1450** qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    ...
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> **mtu 1500** qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    ...
```

**Note, that docker0 states always 1500 and changes it's value only if a container ist connected to that network**

```
$ ip a
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    ...
3: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    ...
17: vethe4b452f@if16: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default 
    ...
```

### Custom Network

I also tried to just create a custom network with a defined `MTU` instead of setting the `MTU` via `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. **This did not work and I don't know why**

`docker network create --opt com.docker.network.mtu=1450 CustomMTU`

Comment: OH MY GOD thank you for this ...I was getting really tired from these random fails. By the way, I think that almost everybody with WireGuard VPN will have this issue, so yeah if you are reading this and are using WG VPN, just check that you have this configured correctly.